# Memory leak with Android camera2 API

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks

I am facing some weird memory leak using camera2 api. Tested with https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic adding empty activity to launch the camera activity and close it then launch again, I get following trace:

> 11-12 12:52:19.506 16069-16078/com.example.android.camera2basic E/StrictMode: A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
>                                                                                 java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'release' not called
>                                                                                     at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:180)
>                                                                                     at android.view.Surface.setNativeObjectLocked(Surface.java:511)
>                                                                                     at android.view.Surface.(Surface.java:179)
>                                                                                     at com.example.android.camera2basic.Camera2BasicFragment.createCameraPreviewSession(Camera2BasicFragment.java:684)
>                                                                                     at com.example.android.camera2basic.Camera2BasicFragment.access$400(Camera2BasicFragment.java:74)
>                                                                                     at com.example.android.camera2basic.Camera2BasicFragment$2.onOpened(Camera2BasicFragment.java:194)
>                                                                                     at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$1.run(CameraDeviceImpl.java:134)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
>   11-12 12:52:19.506 16069-16078/com.example.android.camera2basic W/System.err: StrictMode VmPolicy violation with POLICY_DEATH; shutting down.

I use

```
StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
    .detectAll()
    .penaltyLog()
    .penaltyDeath()
    .build());
```

Running on LG Nexus 5X, OS 7.1.2

Any ideas if this is something to worry about?

Thanks.

Comment: On a first view the result seems to be correct. The `Surface` instance is created but never closed explicitly anywhere (may be it is closed implicitly?). I would try to change the surface to a field and close it in `onDisconnected` and `onError`.

Comment: `Surface` should get released when `TextureView` is detached from window.

Comment: `SurfaceTexture` gets released when `TextureView` is detached from window, not sure does that release `Surface`. But I tried to manually release it, then started getting errors about InstanceCountViolation for `CameraActivity`

Answer (score 1):

This is more or less a spurious error, due to the framework handling of Surfaces in some cases.

It is not an issue you can do anything about, but in practice it should not cause you any real memory leaks.